# GCP Workflows - Executions are not shown

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I used to be able to view the executions of a workflow, but one day it simply stopped showing up.

Is there a particular permission that is required?

I am already have Organisation Administrator role.

[Workflow executions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajWVI.png)